# Atom - Having trouble with arrow functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, arrow-functions

I am using the Atom text editor and I'm having trouble using arrow functions. Whenever I use an arrow function, I get an error message.

For example, for the code:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
console.log(x.map((a,b) => a+2));
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I was wondering if I need to get another package or if anyone might have an idea on how I can fix this? I am a noob so any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: Is that the only code in the file?

Comment: The code provided looks good.  Any chance you can provide more information about your atom setup?

Comment: Did you configure the editor to allow ES6?

Comment: Also, assuming the error is in the browser, what other JS scripts are being loaded?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions everyone! @BrettDeWoody Yes, that was the only code in the file, but the same thing has happened when I have used arrow functions in other files as well.

Comment: @epascarello  I added the ES6 package but maybe I need to do something else to configure it properly? I'm very new to this so it's definitely possible i'm missing something

Comment: Is the file set to be parsed as `javascript`. You can view this in the bottom right corner of Atom.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Yes I set it to javascript

Comment: To be clear, the error of `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` is being shown in Atom? Or in the browser?

Comment: The error appears in Atom

Comment: What packages do you have in Atom? It sounds like a linter is involved. You can get a list with `apm list` in your terminal. Add it to the question, not in the comments.